# 'in' operator in JavaScript. String comparison

Tags: javascript, string

Hi I'm new in JavaScript and i find a basic problem:

When I use that piece of code in Python:

```
'a' in 'aaa'
```

I get `True`

When I do the same in JavaScript I get Error:

```
TypeError: Cannot use 'in' operator to search for 'a' in aaa
```

How to get similar result as in Python?

Comment: Another common point of confusion is the `is` operator in Python which means something totally different in C#. Python `is` means object identity comparison, C# `is` is like Python `isinstance`.

Comment: As a general rule, javascript and Python are quite different; take care with comparison (e.g. use === in javascript), arrays (don't use `in` to go through a javascript array), dictionaries and objects (separate in Python, same thing in javascript), types (javascript is dynamically and loosely typed, Python is dynamically but strongly typed) and so on.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

I think one way is to use [String.indexOf()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/indexOf)

```
'aaa' .indexOf('a') > -1
```

In javascript the [in operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/in) is used to check whether an object has a property

Answer (score 5):

You're looking for `indexOf`.

```
'aaa'.indexOf('a') == 0 //if a char exists in the string, indexOf will return
                        // the index of the first instance of the char
'aaa'.indexOf('b') == -1 //if a char doesn't exist in the string, indexOf will return -1
```

Answer (score 2):

Duplicate ([How to check whether a string contains a substring in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1789945/how-can-i-check-if-one-string-contains-another-substring))

Try this:

```
var s = "aaaabbbaaa";
var result = s.indexOf("a") > -1;
```

Answer (score 2):

[From MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/in):

> The in operator returns true if the specified property is in the specified object.

You're interested in [`'aaa'.indexOf('a')`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/indexOf).

Answer (score 2):

try:

```
if('aaa'.search('a')>-1){
   //
}
```

Comment: you can use includes()              like  if('aaa'.includes('a'))